# Unhandled rejection using setState in .map loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to `setState` within a loop but receiving `Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'state' of undefined` as an error.

The loop contains API data that is contained within another `state` and within this loop I am trying to `setState` using `onClick= {() => this.setState({clicked: !this.state.clicked})}` to change the `className` of an `div` as `className={this.state.clicked ? 'closed' : 'open'}`.

I have never come across this issue before but granted I haven't used within a loop before either.

Here is a stripped example of the code

```
class Rates extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        dailyRatesDates: [],
        clicked: true,
    }
}
componentDidMount(){
    ... //calling API data and passing as setState to dailyRatesDates
} 

render() {
  return (
    <span>
      {this.state.dailyRatesDates.length > 0 &&
         <WrapperMobile> 
            {this.state.dailyRatesDates.map(function(i,index){
               return(
                  <div key={index}>
                     {i.rate_plans.map(function(j,index){
                        return(
                          <div key={index} className="expander">
                             <h2 onClick= {() => this.setState({clicked: !this.state.clicked})}>
                                <p>{j.name}</p>
                             </h2>
                             <div className={`expander__content ${this.state.clicked ? 'closed' : 'open'}`}>
                                ...
                             </div>
                          </div>
                        )
                      })}
                    </div>
                  )
                })}
             </WrapperMobile>
           </div>
         }
      </span>
    );
  }
}
```

If you need to see more then let me know but this should give basis to what I am trying to achieve and further more the issue that `${this.state.clicked ? 'closed' : 'open'}` causing in this scenario.

Comment: In the example - yes. It the actual code it all makes sense without things stripped out. These in example will work as is, if I can figure out why the `clicked` `setState` is undefined, but I agree it's looking a little whacky here.

Comment: It would be a little more helpful if you had a runnable snippet. StackOverflow allows you to embed runnable JavaScript snippets, which works well for situations like this.

Comment: They aren't the issue at hand.

Comment: @MikeBell. Thanks - I shall do that now.

Comment: try changing the `.map(function(...) {` callback to `.map((...) => {` - because the issue is most likely with what `this` is

Comment: Of course. Let me try that now @JaromandaX.

Comment: Yup, that was it. Could you put as an answer so I can accept and close this question. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two lines

```
this.state.dailyRatesDates.map(function(i,index){
i.rate_plans.map(function(j,index){
```

could result 'this' to be 'undefined'.

Changing to Arrow functions

```
this.state.dailyRatesDates.map((i,index) => {
i.rate_plans.map((j,index) => {
```

*preserves* `this` from the enclosing context.